# Python data type, what kind of data structure it is?

Tags: python

```
reshape, crop = {
1: ((1952, 3264), (1944, 3240)),
2: ((2480, 4128), (2464, 4100)),
}

offset = {1: 6404096, 2: 10270208,}[ver]

#where ver is defined as a dictionary

ver = {
    'RP_ov5647': 1,
    'RP_imx219': 2,
    }[camera.exif_tags['IFD0.Model']]
```

What kind of structures are these? `ver` reported as type int. I'm confused.
How did [ver] work in the assignment to `offset`?

Comment: Type of what? I just see dictionaries.

Comment: "I'm confused" So are we.

Comment: What are you referring to as *"it"*? Why build a dictionary then assign its keys (integers) but completely ignore its values (tuples of tuples of integers)? What are you trying to *do*?

Comment: `ver` is not a dictionary; it's the value associated with whichever key `camera.exif_tags['IFD0.Model']` evaluates to. You are just indexing a `dict` literal on the right-hand side of the assignment to `ver`.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see here...

```
reshape, crop = {
1: ((1952, 3264), (1944, 3240)),
2: ((2480, 4128), (2464, 4100)),
}
```

This here is defining a dictionary with keys `1` and `2`.  Attached to each key is a tuple of tuples.  I believe there are more entries in the real code, going by the comma on the last item.  However, most of this object gets lost to garbage collection.  The tuple assignment to `reshape` and `crop` will result in only the keys being stored.  So the result of this thing is the same as:

```
reshape = 1
crop = 2
```

Interesting if useless.  Next...

```
offset = {1: 6404096, 2: 10270208,}[ver]
```

So this here defines another dictionary with keys `1` and `2` and long integer values associated with them.  It then indexes this dictionary with `ver` and assigns the value at this index to `offset`.  Since `ver` isn't defined yet, this would really result in an exception.  Let's say that the following code was given before the previous:

```
#where ver is defined as a dictionary

ver = {
    'RP_ov5647': 1,
    'RP_imx219': 2,
    }[camera.exif_tags['IFD0.Model']]
```

Here we have yet another dictionary.  This time the keys are `'RP_ov5647'` and `'RP_imx219'` with values of `1` and `2`.  This dictionary is indexed with a value of `camera.exif_tags['IFD0.Model']`.  Assuming that `camera.exif_tags` is an object with keyed indexes, one of the indexes is `'IFD0.Model'` and the resulting value is either `'RP_ov5647'` or `'RP_imx219'`, `ver` will be assigned either `1` or `2`.

So that 1 or 2 will be used to index our above offset value resulting in offset being assigned either `6404096` or `10270208`

In short, it's all a syntactically valid bunch of nothing.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thank you very much. this is part of the code that I cant understand from pi camera documentation. The complete code is to extract the tagged raw image data as metadata of the jpeg output. The numbers are used as resolution for reshaping the array. Ver is version, w,r,t two versions of pi camera. That's it. I just wanted to write my own code by modified it. The code from the doc has some limitations as for my use.

Comment: Thank you very much btw!!!!! very appreciated !!!!!

Comment: As shown in the other answer, I'm pretty sure you posted a mangled version of real code.  The fact that it's still usable is a testament to the complete chaos that is Python.

Comment: data = data.reshape(reshape)[:crop[0], :crop[1]]  when I use this line after 'reshape, crop ' part. What it does exactly??  inside the bracket, which tuple does reshape points to? (1952,3264) or (1944,3240)?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your initial statement isn't going to do what (I think) you want: you have two variables on the left of the assignment, but only a single value -- a dictionary -- on the right.  I think you're missing `[ver]` at the end.  As given, the statement will build the dictionary, extract the keys (1, 2), and assign those to the variables, ignoring the dimensional tuples.

The variable `ver` above is an integer that you looked up in a dictionary.

This code seems designed to start with a model name and look up appropriate parameters based on that model.  Let's look at the code in its proper order, and with a couple of intermediate variables.

```
# Dictionary to look up version number (1 or 2),
#   given the model name.
model_to_version = {
    'RP_ov5647': 1,
    'RP_imx219': 2,
    }

# Get the model name from the camera info object.
# Here on Stack Overflow, we have no idea of the structure,
#   but merely have to trust that this works.
model_name = camera.exif_tags['IFD0.Model']

# Now, get the version number we're using as an internal key.
# This will return 1 or 2.
version = model_to_version[model_name]

# The offset look-up is unchanged.
offset = {1: 6404096, 2: 10270208}[version]

# Dictionary to look up sizing information (shape & crop).
# Each entry is a pair of x-y dimension pairs.
size_info = {
    1: ((1952, 3264), (1944, 3240)),
    2: ((2480, 4128), (2464, 4100)),
}

# Finally, look up the proper set of sizes:
shaping, crop = size_info[ver]
```

After all of this, we have `shaping` and `crop` with the appropriate dimensions for this camera model, and `offset` has the appropriate pixel offset (I assume) in a stream of input.

Is that what you needed?

Comment: Point ... my phrasing is wrong.  The *syntax* is valid, but the *semantics* are almost certainly *not* what the programmer wanted.  I'll fix my posting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input!!!

Comment: its just the tiny part of a program to extract raw image from pi camera. The raw data is tagged at the end of standard JPEG output as metadata. So I have to do a separation. The numbers were the resolutions for reshaping the array. I just cant understand what was wrote in the doc.